# Powershell GUI difference on Win10 and Win11

Tags: powershell

I have a simple Powershell app that displays a GUI. I used it on Windows 10 with this command  to run this powershell script **powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -WindowStyle Hidden -File "C:\app.ps1"** On Windows 10 I only see app icon in taskbar and app window on desktop

[image]

But in Windows 11, different story :( Opening the app opens app but it also opens terminal window maximized.

[image]

Any idea how to avoid showing terminal window and why is there a difference between Windows 10 and 11?

Comment: you now which versions is powershell on w10 and w11 ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you are starting PowerShell from a BATCH/CMD file, since I don't believe a shortcut/link would result in the extra window.

While I do not have Windows 11, I believe the problem you are experiencing can, under certain circumstances, exist in Windows 10.  I say this because I remember having weird and random problems and wound up using the following style of execution to play it safe:

```
@START "My App" /MIN powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -WindowStyle Hidden -File "C:\app.ps1" & GOTO :EOF
```

The command can be broken down into 3 parts.  This first part starts PowerShell minimized in a different window.  The minimizing of PowerShell probably isn't necessary, but what is important is this that allows CMD to continue execution of the batch file, **and exit the batch file**, while PowerShell does its thing.

```
@START "My App" /MIN
```

This is basically your command with the the added `-NoProfile` to speed up execution.

```
powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -WindowStyle Hidden -File "C:\app.ps1"
```

The `GOTO :EOF` is only necessary if the command isn't the last command in the BATCH/CMD script and you want immediate exit of the script.

```
& GOTO :EOF
```